# is there an odd prime p such that (n/p)=1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, legendre-symbol

For any positive integer n, is there exists an odd prime p such that $(\dfrac{n}{p}) = 1$?

i think that it will be true.. but i don't know what is right.

what i have done is that .. when n is even, power of 2 can be deprived form n and

we can make odd number b. so  $(\dfrac{b}{p})$ can be legendre symbol.

i want to know the fact about that and the reason too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Pick your favorite square $m^2$, where $m$ is relatively prime to $n$ and has opposite parity to $n$; then any prime $p$ dividing $m^2-n$ is odd and has the property that $\big(\frac np\big) = \big(\frac {m^2}p\big) = \big(\frac mp\big)^2=1$.

Comment: Well, if the OP's favourite square happens to be $n\pm 1$, they may have to resort to a second-favorite.